# Pomodoro Clock JS Modularisation

Tags: javascript, beginner, timer

I am beginner on Javascript and i made a pomodoro clock for freecodecamp project with vanilla Javascript.

I was read few articles about modular and functional javascript and i want to use these techniques. But when i start writing code, I find it difficult to use these techniques. I will appreciated if anyone review my code and refactor it with modular patterns. Then I can compare the two codes, and that helps me a lot. And if there are bad implementations, please tell me my mistakes.

```js
var addSession = document.querySelector('.add_session');
var decSession = document.querySelector('.dec_session');

var addBreak = document.querySelector('.add_break');
var decBreak = document.querySelector('.dec_break');

var sessionInput = parseInt(document.querySelector('.session_min').innerHTML);
document.querySelector('.session_min').innerHTML = sessionInput;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = sessionInput;


var breakInput = document.querySelector('.break_min').innerHTML;
 breakInput = parseInt(breakInput);
document.querySelector('.break_min').innerHTML = breakInput;

var counterVal = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
 counterVal = parseInt(counterVal);
 counterVal = sessionInput;
 counterVal = counterVal * 60;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counterVal;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;



var startBtn = document.querySelector('.start');
var resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset');
var breakBtn = document.querySelector('.break');




addSession.onclick = function(e) {
 sessionInput += 5;
 document.querySelector('.session_min').innerHTML = sessionInput;
 counterVal = sessionInput * 60;
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
};

decSession.onclick = function(e) {
 if (sessionInput > 5) {
  sessionInput -= 5;
  document.querySelector('.session_min').innerHTML = sessionInput;
  counterVal = sessionInput * 60;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
 }
};

addBreak.onclick = function(e) {
 breakInput += 1;
 document.querySelector('.break_min').innerHTML = breakInput;
 counterVal = breakInput * 60;
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
};

decBreak.onclick = function(e) {
 if (breakInput > 1) {
  breakInput -= 1;
  document.querySelector('.break_min').innerHTML = breakInput;
  counterVal = breakInput * 60;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
 }
};



function timer() {

  counterVal -= 1;
  if (counterVal % 60 >= 10) {
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" +  counterVal % 60;
  } else {
   document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
  }
  if (counterVal === 0) {
   clearInterval(counter);
   startBtn.innerHTML = 'Start';
  }
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 
 if (startBtn.innerHTML === 'Start' && counterVal !== 0) {
  breakBtn.disabled = true;
  startBtn.innerHTML = 'Pause';
  counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

 } else if (startBtn.innerHTML === 'Pause' && counterVal > 0) {
  breakBtn.disabled = false;
  startBtn.innerHTML = 'Start';
  clearInterval(counter);
 }

}, false);

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
 if (startBtn.innerHTML !== 'Pause') {
  counterVal = sessionInput;
  counterVal = counterVal * 60;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counterVal;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
 }

 if (breakBtn.innerHTML === "Work") {
  breakBtn.innerHTML = "Break";
 }
}, false);


breakBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

 if (breakBtn.innerHTML === "Break") {
  addBreak.disabled = false;
  decBreak.disabled = false;
  addSession.disabled = true;
  decSession.disabled = true;
  breakBtn.innerHTML = "Work";
  counterVal = breakInput;
  counterVal = counterVal * 60;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counterVal;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
 } else if (breakBtn.innerHTML === "Work") {
  addBreak.disabled = true;
  decBreak.disabled = true;
  addSession.disabled = false;
  decSession.disabled = false;
  breakBtn.innerHTML = "Break";
  counterVal = sessionInput * 60;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counterVal;
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
 }
 
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="clock_wrapper">
 <h1>Pomodoro Clock</h1>
 <div class="clock">
  <h2 id="counter"></h2>
  <div class="buttons_wrapper">
   <button class="start">Start</button>
   <button class="reset">Reset</button>
   <button class="break">Break</button>
  </div>
  <hr/>
 </div>
 <div class="session_wrap">
  <h3>Session Time</h3>
  <div class="session_time">
   <button class="dec_session bt">-</button>
   <div class="session_min">25</div>
   <button class="add_session bt">+</button>
  </div>
  
 </div>

 <div class="break_wrap">
  <h3>Break Time</h3>
  <div class="break_time">
   <button disabled class="dec_break bt">-</button>
   <div class="break_min">5</div>
   <button disabled class="add_break bt">+</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all delete marker  from HTMl ;-).

First bad thing in your code is a global scope polution. Currently every var and functions 'lives' in global. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice

```
var addSession = document.querySelector('.add_session');
var decSession = document.querySelector('.dec_session');

var addBreak = document.querySelector('.add_break');
var decBreak = document.querySelector('.dec_break');

var sessionInput = parseInt(document.querySelector('.session_min').innerHTML);
```

Bad idea to get state values from html. It should be oposite to this aproach.
For example  var sessionInput  = 25; And then sett it  in html.

```
document.querySelector('.session_min').innerHTML = sessionInput;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = sessionInput;
```

Be more consistent. You can use  document.querySelector('#counter').;

```
var breakInput = document.querySelector('.break_min').innerHTML;
    breakInput = parseInt(breakInput);
document.querySelector('.break_min').innerHTML = breakInput;
```

So you got some states in app to meanage. The good idea is to put them together into one object called state. It will make debuging a piece of cake.
For example:

```
var clockState = {
  breakTime = 0,
  sessionTime = 0,
  counterVal = 0
}
```

Next you can use them like this:

```
someFunction( clockState.breakTime );
```

This below is quite messy:

```
var counterVal = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
    counterVal = parseInt(counterVal);
    counterVal = sessionInput;
    counterVal = counterVal * 60;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counterVal;
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
```

Below better way to solve task like this:

```
counter =  document.querySelector('#counter');
clockState.counterVal = 25 * 60;
counter.innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
```

All variables should be declared at the begining. It makes easier to find them later ;-).

```
var startBtn = document.querySelector('.start');
var resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset');
var breakBtn = document.querySelector('.break');
```

This is old way to meanage events in JS.

```
addSession.onclick = function(e) {
    sessionInput += 5;
    document.querySelector('.session_min').innerHTML = sessionInput;
    counterVal = sessionInput * 60;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
};
```

Today people are using addEventListener:

```
function modifySession(){/* Doing the work*/}
addSession.addEventListener('click',modifySession)
```

//

```
decSession.onclick = function(e) {
    if (sessionInput > 5) {
        sessionInput -= 5;
        document.querySelector('.session_min').innerHTML = sessionInput;
        counterVal = sessionInput * 60;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
    }
};

addBreak.onclick = function(e) {
    breakInput += 1;
    document.querySelector('.break_min').innerHTML = breakInput;
    counterVal = breakInput * 60;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
};

decBreak.onclick = function(e) {
    if (breakInput > 1) {
        breakInput -= 1;
        document.querySelector('.break_min').innerHTML = breakInput;
        counterVal = breakInput * 60;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
    }
};



function timer() {

    counterVal -= 1;
    if (counterVal % 60 >= 10) {
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" +  counterVal % 60;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
    }
    if (counterVal === 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        startBtn.innerHTML = 'Start';
    }
}

startBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (startBtn.innerHTML === 'Start' && counterVal !== 0) {
        breakBtn.disabled = true;
        startBtn.innerHTML = 'Pause';
        counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    } else if (startBtn.innerHTML === 'Pause' && counterVal > 0) {
        breakBtn.disabled = false;
        startBtn.innerHTML = 'Start';
        clearInterval(counter);
    }

}, false);

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (startBtn.innerHTML !== 'Pause') {
        counterVal = sessionInput;
        counterVal = counterVal * 60;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counterVal;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
    }

    if (breakBtn.innerHTML === "Work") {
        breakBtn.innerHTML = "Break";
    }
}, false);


breakBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){

    if (breakBtn.innerHTML === "Break") {
        addBreak.disabled = false;
        decBreak.disabled = false;
        addSession.disabled = true;
        decSession.disabled = true;
        breakBtn.innerHTML = "Work";
        counterVal = breakInput;
        counterVal = counterVal * 60;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counterVal;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
    } else if (breakBtn.innerHTML === "Work") {
        addBreak.disabled = true;
        decBreak.disabled = true;
        addSession.disabled = false;
        decSession.disabled = false;
        breakBtn.innerHTML = "Break";
        counterVal = sessionInput * 60;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = counterVal;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = Math.floor(counterVal / 60) + ":" + "0" + counterVal % 60;
    }

}, false);
```

Currently your application is about 130 lines long.
Try to make it 65. And learn the DRY principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself.

If you are looking for challenges then try to write simple calculator.

Comment: thank you. I will try to apply what you say. By the way i made a simple calculator before pomodoro clock